# CS50-pset2: Readability. Incorrect outcome

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

When I run my code, the outcome has failed to show the exact result based on the texts given in the problem set. Although, it showed the grade, the result is incorrect. The text is : "Would you like them here or there? I would not like them here or there. I would not like them anywhere."(Grade 2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQzw2.png)

Supposedly, the result for the text is "Grade 2". However, it shows all grades instead.

```
enter code here
int main(void)
{

string s = get_string("Text: ");
printf("%s\n",s);

int count_letters = 0; //To count letters (uppercase & lowercase)
int count_words = 1; //To count words
int count_sentences = 0; //To count sentences
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)



if (isalpha(s[i]))
{
    if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z' )||( s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
    {
        count_letters++;
    }
if (s[i] == ' ')
{
        count_words++;
}
if (s[i] == '.' || s[i] =='!' || s[i] == '?')
{
       count_sentences++;
}
//printf("%i count_letter(s)\n", count_letters);
//printf("%i count_words(s)\n", count_words);
//printf("%i sentence(s)\n", count_sentences);

//Coleman-Liau index
float L = (count_letters / (float) count_words) * 100;
float S = (count_sentences / (float) count_words) * 100;
int grade = round (0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S -15.8);
  
if (grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
else if (grade >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
else
    {
        printf("Grade %.d\n", grade);
    }
}
```

}

Is there any problem with my code? How can I fix my code in order to receive the exact outcome. I've been doing this problem set for almost 2 days :'/. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think something might be off with your syntax, I don't see that you have brackets after the loop

Comment: Your conditions are wrong. Think about that `isalpha(s[i])` check, and the nested conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of letters, sentences, and words inside of the loop and calculate Coleman-Liau's index outside of the loop.

Don't calculate something in a loop and try to get specific output from within it as well, it never ends well. So in conclusion, calculate your values in the loop and do everything else outside of it.

```
int count_letters = 0; //To count letters (uppercase & lowercase)
int count_words = 1; //To count words
int count_sentences = 0; //To count sentences
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++){
     // get the amounts in the loop
     if (isalpha(s[i]))
     {
            if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                count_letters++;
            }
            if (s[i] == ' ')
            {
                count_words++;
            }
            if (s[i] == '.' || s[i] == '!' || s[i] == '?')
            {
                count_sentences++;
            }
      }
}

//Calculate Coleman-Liau outside of it and get the correct grade from your if statements
```

Comment: Your code still contains one of the main problems of the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have three distinct categories to count, I would create a function for each of these.

For example, based on your code, you could create a function to count characters (you don't need `isdigit` function here, non-digit characters are already filtered out by the algorithm itself):

```
int get_letters_count(char *text_str)
{
    int count_letters = 0;

    int text_len = strlen(text_str);

    for (int i = 0; i < text_len; i++) {

        if (   (text_str[i] >= 'a' && text_str[i] <= 'z')
            || (text_str[i] >= 'A' && text_str[i] <= 'Z')
            || (text_str[i] >= '0' && text_str[i] <= '9')) {

            count_letters++;
        }
    }

    return count_letters;
}
```

This approach of breaking down your program will make it much easier to develop.

Here is a very crude implementation based on the [Coleman–Liau index Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Liau_index):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int get_letters_count(char *text_str)
{
    int count_letters = 0;

    int text_len = strlen(text_str);

    for (int i = 0; i < text_len; i++) {

        if (   (text_str[i] >= 'a' && text_str[i] <= 'z')
            || (text_str[i] >= 'A' && text_str[i] <= 'Z')
            || (text_str[i] >= '0' && text_str[i] <= '9')) {

            count_letters++;
        }
    }

    return count_letters;
}

int get_words_count(char *text_str)
{
    int count_words = 0;

    int text_len = strlen(text_str);

    for (int i = 0; i < text_len; i++) {

        if (text_str[i] == ' ') {

            count_words++;
        }
    }

    if (count_words)
        count_words++;

    return count_words;
}

bool word_is_acronym(char *word)
{
    bool ret = true;

    for (; *word && *word != ' '; word++) {

        if (   *word != '.'
            && *word < 'A' || *word > 'Z') {

            ret = false;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int get_sentences_count(char *text_str)
{
    int count_sentences = 0;
    int text_len = strlen(text_str);

    char *last_word = &text_str[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < text_len; i++) {

        if (   text_str[i] == ' '
            && i < (text_len - 1)) {

            last_word = &text_str[i + 1];
        }

        bool end_mark =    text_str[i] == '.'
                        || text_str[i] == '!'
                        || text_str[i] == '?';

        if (   end_mark           
            && word_is_acronym(last_word) == false) {

            count_sentences++;
        }
    }

    return count_sentences;
}

int main(void)
{
    char text_str[] = "Existing computer programs that measure readability are based "
                      "largely upon subroutines which estimate number of syllables, "
                      "usually by counting vowels. The shortcoming in estimating syllables "
                      "is that it necessitates keypunching the prose into the computer. "
                      "There is no need to estimate syllables since word length in letters "
                      "is a better predictor of readability than word length in syllables. "
                      "Therefore, a new readability formula was computed that has for its "
                      "predictors letters per 100 words and sentences per 100 words. "
                      "Both predictors can be counted by an optical scanning device, and "
                      "thus the formula makes it economically feasible for an organization "
                      "such as the U.S. Office of Education to calibrate the readability of "
                      "all textbooks for the public school system.";

    int count_letters   = get_letters_count(text_str);
    int count_words     = get_words_count(text_str);
    int count_sentences = get_sentences_count(text_str);;

    if (   count_letters   > 0
        && count_words     > 0
        && count_sentences > 0) {

        float L = ((count_letters * 100) / count_words);
        float S = ((count_sentences * 100) / count_words);
        float grade = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

        printf("grade = %.01f\n", grade);

    } else {

        printf("bad input\n");
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
grade = 14.5
```

Parsing text can be very trick, though.
Once you get a first version working with a known input such as this, try to expand your data set and keep improving your program.

This program is also far from being computationally efficient. If that becomes a bottleneck, you could optimize the functions or maybe reduce the number of loops grouping the functions in a single loop.

Certainly most times it's better to start with a crude working solution and improve from there instead of attempting a more sophisticated/complete solution right from the beginning.